# count xml elements/nodes using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

this could be duplicate, but I found nothing useful so far.

I'm trying to count `nodes/childs` of `XML` file using `simplexml`.

I've tried this.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("./file.xml");
echo count($xml->rss->channel->item);
```

and

```
echo count($xml->item);
```

but just outputting `0`.

here is snapshot of `XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <title>PUDRA Pudra Ceket Ceket</title>
      <link>http://www.trendyol.com//Pudra-Ceket-IW6140005046/UrunDetay/31066/9188683?</link>
       <description>36 pudra pudra ceket ıw6140005046 ipekyol ceket kadın</description>
       <g:urunid>1423905</g:urunid>
       <g:id>1423905_14</g:id>
    </item>
    <item>
        ....
    </item>
```

Comment: it's not picking `<g:id>1423905_14</g:id>` while printing single item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo count($xml->channel->item);
```

**EDIT:**

Why you have to it this way? Because form `simplexml_load_file()` you get a structure like this (`print_r($xml);`):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
```

Because of this structure you have to access the object like i said (above).

Comment: Thanks..a little more help, when I try to print the product, like `print_r($xml->channel->item);`. then it is just printing only that nodes that don't have `g:` in it, e.g. description, title, link etc. How to get rest?

Comment: @MubinKhalid The elements are in a different xml namespace, if you want to access them see here: http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302